# Angular 8 + Bootstrap 3 Hamburger Menu Not Working

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 to follow a tutorial but they create their own menu, so I was wondering how I could use bootstraps hamburger menu. I have a directive for dropdowns, but it doesn't work when I place it on the button tag or anywhere else.

I don't want to use jquery or bootstrap.js, but only Angular tools.

This is the HTML template.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header" appDropdown>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" appDropdown>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand">Salsa @ Rio</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" appDropdown>
        <li class="dropdown" appDropdown>
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Courses <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a routerLink="/courses/0">Salsa 1</a></li>
            <li><a routerLink="/courses/1">Salsa 2</a></li>
            <li><a routerLink="/courses/2">Salsa 3</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a routerLink="/courses/3">Cuban Salsa Starter</a></li>
            <li><a routerLink="/courses/4">Cuban Salsa Foundation</a></li>
            <li><a routerLink="/courses/5">Cuban Salsa 1</a></li>
            <li><a routerLink="/courses/6">Cuban Salsa 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

This is the directive:

```
export class DropdownDirective {
  @HostBinding('class.open') isOpen = false;
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) toggleOpen(event: Event) {
    this.isOpen = this.elRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target) ? !this.isOpen : false;
  }
  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {}
}
```

Comment: You could try [angular bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples#navbar). They have an example implementation of a collapsible navbar that you could use

Answer (score -1):

Try Angular Material. Follow "https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api"